# Cross validation with Pearson correlation coefficient - is testing one tailed enough?

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, pearson-r

My method of cross validation is to first split my sample into two sub-samples, with 80% respectively 20% of the observations, and then to correlate the predicted values of my model (created with the bigger sample) with the actually observed values (of the smaller sample).

This correlation can be tested for significance and here is my question about that process: In order for the model to make sense, the correlation should be greater than 0. If the correlation is negative (and significant), my model makes exactly the opposite predictions it should do and is therefore not useful. Thus, is it in the end not already enough to only have a one tailed test if the correlation is greater 0?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a two sided test.

A one sided test *assumes* that the "other side" is impossible. But you yourself said that it's possible. Undesirable and improbable, to be sure, but not impossible.

In addition, one-sided p-values are known to lead to [extremely overconfident inferences](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/pvalues3.pdf) (see page 3).

Comment: If I test one-tailed, a negative correlation is still possible and if it occurs, I just don't reject the null r <= 0. What is the use for me to see if a negative correlation is significant?

Comment: @00schneider that depends: do you believe that substantive negative correlation is possible? "Significant" is a meaningless term. Are you interested in whether it's significantly different from zero, or significantly greater than zero?

Answer (score 1):

If one were to do a test of correlation, I think a one-tailed test makes some sense in this instance, but a significant negative correlation would be somewhat suprising and notable (I'd want to investigate why negating the predictions would have a better-than-random association) -- so there might still be some reason to consider a two tailed test.

However - and this is a big caveat - *correlation* is not of itself a good measure of how good the predictions are. If my predictions were all a million too high, or all 1% of what they should be, they would usually be regarded as *terrible* predictions, but they might still be highly correlated with the actual outcomes.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. Do you have a recommendation to measure the quality of prediction?

Comment: something like [mean square error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) / [root mean square deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation) (or something similar that more accurately reflects your loss function), perhaps.